# $_SERVER variable to identify where request is coming from?

Tags: php, request

I need to know what page a user made the request FROM ...

`$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` tells me what file the request is made to, however I want to know what file / page the user was on when the request was made.

Comment: you are thinking perhaps of the easily spoofable and frequently empty `referrer` I suspect. You'd be advised not to rely upon it or trust it

Comment: @RamRaider Put that in an answer and I will accept.

Comment: Some Antivirus applications remove that from header. You can not rely on that.

Comment: @MarkusZeller This was to quickly debug a problem and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Some Antivirus applications remove that referrer from the header, so it may be empty, then. You can not rely on that field.

Answer (score -1):

You can't know where is the request come from, unless it have indicator as if you redirect to any website from Facebook it types in URL "?fbclid=..." as a "get" method so your website knows it comes from Facebook.

Comment: This not the header, it is appended to the URL as query parameter.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that thank you bro